# Sql pull prior day except on Mondays pull Friday thru Sunday

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, date, where-clause

Here is my code for MySql,

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (IF(DAYNAME(CURDATE()) = 'Monday',3,1)) DAY) AND
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (IF(DAYNAME(CURDATE()) = 'Monday',1,1)) DAY)
```

I know how to pull the prior day without time in Sql Server 2008 but I have not been able to get anything to work converting this line of code over from MySql to Sql.

Comment: Converting from `MySQL` to `SQL`?  `SQL` is very ambiguous - what specific flavour of `SQL` are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: We're using Sql server?  I didn't know other than that, I was just told it was SQL.

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear, but you'll want something similar to `DateAdd(Day, Case When DatePart(WeekDay, GetDate()) = 2 Then -3 Else -1 End, GetDate())`

Comment: Thank you for your help, that did not work, I know we're using Mircosoft Sql Server 2008 and Navicat Sql Server.

Comment: Please explain what you need to get, don't whos the MySQL conde. An expert at SQL Server can give you an answer only if he clearly understands the question.

Comment: Above is what I used in MySql,  I need to pull in the WHERE Clause the previous day of work, unless it is a Monday, I need to pull work for Friday Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Using 'code' lDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -1) 'code'  I am able to pull yesterdays date, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to pull over the weekend if the day is Monday

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `MySQL` code you've provided, this should work for what you need:

```
Between Cast(DateAdd(Day, Case When DatePart(WeekDay, GetDate()) = 2 Then -3 Else -1 End, GetDate()) As Date)
And     Cast(DateAdd(Day, -1, GetDate()) As Date)
```

The second `If` statement confuses me, since you're always using 1 day regardless of the result.  So, for this I just simplified it to always use yesterday's date.